# Test React component with data from context, can't find element , Vitest, React testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-context

When i try to test the rendering of the options it cant find the element with the options.

This is the error that i got:
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "listitem" and name "option1"

```
describe("SelectionDropDown", () => {
  it("should", async () => {
    const options = [{ name: "option1" }, { name: "option2" }];

    render(
      <SelectionDropdownContextProvider options={options}>
        <SelectionDropdown />
      </SelectionDropdownContextProvider>,
      {
        wrapper: AllProviders
      }
    );

    const button = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /select service/i });
    const user = userEvent.setup();

    await user.click(button);

    options.forEach((option) => {
      const result = screen.getByRole("listitem", { name: option.name });
      expect(result).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
});
```

```
const SelectionDropdown = () => {
  const { options, serviceType, selectedService, onChange, label } =
    useSelectionDropdownContext();
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const dropdownRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (e) => {
      if (dropdownRef.current && !dropdownRef.current.contains(e.target))
        setIsOpen(false);
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);

    return () => document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="dropdown selection-dropdown" ref={dropdownRef}>
      <div
        tabIndex={0}
        role="button"
        className="btn btn-sm"
        onClick={() => {
          setIsOpen((prev) => !prev);
        }}
      >
        {selectedService ?? label ?? "Select Service"}
        <IoMdArrowDropdown />
      </div>
      {isOpen && (
        <ul
          className="dropdown-content z-[2] menu shadow bg-white rounded-box min-w-full"
          tabIndex={0}
        >
          <CreateButton serviceType={serviceType} />
          <li>
            <a
              onClick={() => {
                setIsOpen(false);
              }}
            >
              None
            </a>
          </li>
          {options?.map((option) => (
            <li key={option.unique_id ? option.unique_id : option.id}>
              <a
                onClick={() => {
                  onChange && onChange(option);
                  setIsOpen(false);
                }}
              >
                {option.name}
              </a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SelectionDropdown;
```

I try to get the correct values from the options so i can see it render proper.